# Select the checkbox using pre-selected data in angular6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, primeng

I want to display a list of roles in the checkbox , If a role has already been selected, the checkbox is selected .

i using this code for return the rolesId :

```
this.Adu.optionId=this.selectedEdit;
this.otionService.GetRolesfoOptionsID(this.Adu).subscribe((data)=>{
  data.forEach(el=>{
    this.selectRoleValue.push(el);

  })
  console.log(this.selectRoleValue)
})
```

this code is work and fill the `this.selectRoleValue` with role has already been selected But the checkbox is not selected.

and in HTML:

```
  <div *ngFor="let role of roles">
    <p-checkbox id="checkbox" value="{{role.id}}" [(ngModel)]="selectRoleValue" label="{{role.description}}" ></p-checkbox>
  </div>
```

whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: We have no idea of what p-checkbox is. But if it works like a standard checkbox, then it will only be selected if `selectRoleValue` is true. Not if `selectedRoleValue` contains a role id. Learn how your directives work, and use a model that fits with how they work.

Comment: @JBNizet ` p-checkbox` is `Primeng` Component

Comment: what is `el`? Why are you converting `selectRoleValue ` to string?

Comment: @zer0 `el` list of selected number  and convert `toString` just for testing

Comment: Add console.log('roles: ' + JSON.stringify(this.roles)) and console.log('roles' + JSON.stringify(this.selectRoleValue)), and post what you get as a result.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @JBNizet return this `roles: [1004,1009,1004,1009]` and this `roles[1004,1009,1004,1009]`

Comment: @Justcode i cant do this man

Comment: So they are numbers. But you're using string interpolation to pass the value to the checkbox. So it receives a string. I guess that's the problem. Use `[value]="role.id"` (do the same for the label while you're at it). That's the proper way to pass inputs. Note that you've posted the value of roles twice, and not the vlue of selectRoleValue.

Answer (score -1):

You would push id with string format to selectRoleValue

```
this.selectRoleValue.push(el + '');
```